# Checking Cursor has any data

Tags: java, android

I am parsing data from data database. The problem I am facing is every time when application start it fetch data by calling `dataList()`. Now, I want to use a condition that will check if cusror is `empty` only then fecth data from database or I don't want any duplicate data in database. I was tried following code but didn't succeeded

```
boolean isEmpty = cursor.getCount() < 1;
        if(!isEmpty){
            cursor = db.rawQuery("my query..", null);
        }else{
            dataList();
            cursor = db.rawQuery("my query..", null);
        }
```

Comment: No need for tags in titles. The tag system takes care of that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
boolean isEmpty;
if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0)
{
isEmpty=false;
}
else
{
isEmpty=true;
}

if(isEmpty){
          cursor = db.rawQuery("my query..", null);
        }else{
            dataList();
            cursor = db.rawQuery("my query..", null);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       if (!(mCursor.moveToFirst()) || mCursor.getCount() ==0){
       {
          dataList();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("my query..", null);
      }else{
           cursor = db.rawQuery("my query..", null);
       }
```